# UITableViewCell and UILabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'm adding two custom `UILabel` to a section of my `UITableView` in this way:

```
//in .h file:
NSArray *listaopzioni;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listaopzioni;

//in .m file:
self.listaopzioni = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Strumenti",@"Help & Credits", nil] retain];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ([indexPath section]==0) {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        UILabel *slogan= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height)];
        slogan.text=[listaopzioni objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        slogan.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
        slogan.font= [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        slogan.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:slogan];
        [slogan release];


    } 
}
```

All woks perfectly, but when I slide up and down the tableview (trying to cover the cells below the `UINavigationBar`) I get a strange effect: the text is overlapped just making each letter thicker.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called everytime the cell becomes visible.
That is why it creates labels everytime you scroll.
The solution is to put Label creation when you create the cell:

```
 if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if ([indexPath section]==0) {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    UILabel *slogan= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height)];
    slogan.text=[listaopzioni objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    slogan.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    slogan.font= [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    slogan.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:slogan];
    [slogan release];


   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCells (when used properly) get reused, which means after they've been created, they keep their created state, i.e. the label has been added to your cell. What you need to do is make use of this cell reuse to your advantage:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel slogan;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        slogan = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height)];
        slogan.tag = 2121; // Any unique-to-the-cell, positive integer
        slogan.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
        slogan.font= [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
        slogan.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:slogan];
    } else {
        slogan = [cell viewWithTag:2121]; // Must match slogan.tag
    }

    if ([indexPath section]==0) {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        slogan.text=[listaopzioni objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } 
}
```